# What is the cleanest way to collect children of nested lists in Scala?

Tags: scala

Imagine I have a 3 or more level nested list of lists (or any other collection) such as

```
val items: Seq[Seq[Seq[Int]]] = Seq(Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(4,5,6), Seq(4,5,6)), Seq(Seq(1,2,3), Seq(4,5,6), Seq(4,5,6)))
```

What is the cleanest way to traverse through this collection and collect children based on boolean rule.

Such as given the following rule

```
(item) => item % 2 == 0
```

It returns

```
 Seq(2,4,6,4,6,2,4,6,4,6)
```

without flatmaping/flattening the list or using mutable collections!

Comment: `items` has type `Seq[Any]`. The question you should be asking yourself is: "Could I use/get something more type-safe?"

Comment: @Jubobs, sorry - I wrote it without running in console. But I am sure you are intelligent enough to understand what I mean.

Comment: Is the nesting level, "3 or more", consistent for any given instance?  If not then @Jubobs is right, you are dealing with type `Seq[Any]`.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `flatMap`? Going from a nested list to a flat list will (almost?) invariably involve some sort of flattening

Comment: Considered using `scalaz.Tree`, or any other tree structure instead?

Answer (score 3):

Sometime ago some one asked a similar question about nested `Option`s. I provided a generic solution pattern which should work for any monadic structure.

Just make sure that you have a nested monadic type... it will not work with Seq[Any]

I will just extend that to deal with `Seq`'s

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

case class Flattener[W[_], WW, T](fn : WW => W[T])

implicit def seqRecFlattenFn[WW, T](
  implicit f: Flattener[Seq, WW, T] = Flattener((ww: WW) => Seq(ww))
) = Flattener((ww: Seq[WW]) => ww.flatMap(f.fn))

def seqRecursiveFlatten[WW, T](www: Seq[WW])(
  implicit f : Flattener[Seq, Seq[WW], T]
) = f.fn(www)

val nestedSeq1 = Seq(Seq(Seq(Seq(5, 10), Seq(20, 30))))
// nestedSeq1: Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Int]]]] = List(List(List(List(5, 10), List(20, 30))))

val flatSeq1 = seqRecursiveFlatten(nestedSeq1)
// flatSeq1: Seq[Int] = List(5, 10, 20, 30)

val nestedSeq2 = Seq(Seq(Seq(Seq(Seq(Seq(Seq(5, 10), Seq(20, 30)))))))
// nestedSeq2: Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Seq[Int]]]]]]] = List(List(List(List(List(List(List(5, 10), List(20, 30)))))))

val flatSeq2 = seqRecursiveFlatten(nestedSeq)
// flatSeq2: Seq[Int] = List(5, 10, 20, 30)
```

Now you have a flat Seq so apply any filtering or anything that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with arbitrarily nested lists, then you have to deal with a Seq[Any]:

```
def flatFilter(src: Seq[Any], pred: (Int => Boolean)): Seq[Int] = {
  if (src.isEmpty) 
    Seq.empty
  else src.head match {
    case car: Seq[Any] =>
      flatFilter(car, pred) ++ flatFilter(src.tail, pred)
    case car: Int =>
      if (pred(car)) 
        car +: flatFilter(src.tail, pred)
      else 
        flatFilter(src.tail, pred)
    case _ => flatFilter(src.tail, pred)
  }
}
```

Comment: No... you can keep it type-safe. There is not need to involve `Any`s. Look at my answer.

Comment: If there is a defined level of nesting, then yes you can keep it type safe. Not if it involves arbitrary nesting, however. Edited to reflect that.